# Firestore Set field ID to variable

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add a new field to document add call it for example `5`.
I have variable which store the field name I want to use.

So when I'm adding a new field I want to call it `5`
Code:

```
let length = "5";
await firestore()
            .collection(groupID)
            .doc('jobs-list')
            .update({
                length: licenseNumber,
            });
```

The problem here is that the field name is setting to `length` and I want it to be `5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JavaScript's `[]` notation for this:

```
let length = "5";
await firestore()
    .collection(groupID)
    .doc('jobs-list')
    .update({
        [length]: licenseNumber,
    });
```